# cannot figure out how to use re.sub and iterate over a list

Tags: python

I want it to iterate over the list and check whether each of the items in the list is in the var txt and the replace them, if they are there, with a blank space.  As you can see, I can only get the first item in the list to be substituted.  How do I get this to iterate over every item in the list?  Thanks.

```
import re

txt='affirmed and the affirmance and AFFIRMED and Affirm case'

wordList = ['case', 'affirm\w+', '(ca\w+)']
for word in wordList:
    out = re.sub(wordList[0], '', txt, re.I)
    #out = re.sub(r'\Abaffirm.+', '', txt, re.IGNORECASE)

print txt
print out
```

OUTPUT:

```
affirmed and the affirmance and AFFIRMED and Affirm case
affirmed and the affirmance and AFFIRMED and Affirm
```

Comment: Thanks Obidian Age.  Was trying to figure out that formatting but you already handled it.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note here:

1. You have a for loop where each iteration you're accessing the first entry (`wordList[0]`) instead of the current entry (`word`).
2. You're overwritting your output every iteration, so only the last entry in `wordList` will be removed.

So, working loop might look something like this:

```
wordList = ['case', 'affirm\w+', '(ca\w+)']
out = txt
for word in wordList:
    out = re.sub(word, '', out, re.I)

print txt
print out
```

After your advice, which worked, I edited it a bit further, shortening it, to this.

```
import re
txt='affirmed and the affirmance and AFFIRMED and Affirm case'
wordList = ['affirm\w+', '(ca\w+)']
for word in wordList:
    txt = re.sub(word, '', txt, re.I)
print txt
```